# C++ How can i modify a map from another class in a class

Tags: c++, class, dictionary

I have a class "Editor" and a class "TileMap".

I'd like to be able to modify my Tilemap class, more specifically the std::map which is in Tilemap class, with my Editor class.

More clearly i wan't to do this:

```
class Editor
{
private:
    std::map <int, tilemap> m_tilemap; // <--- i want this map

public:
    void target(std::map <int, tilemap> tilemap) // <---- to target this map
    {
        /*  ?   */
    }

    void putABlock(sf::Vector3i coord) // <---- and modify it through several methods...
    {
       /* modify the map */
    }

};
```

"tilemap", (with minus 't') is a struct, with an int, a bool and a sf::sprite.

I know that i have probably to use pointer or reference, but i couldn't succeed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code that you want:

```
class Editor
{
private:
    // Use a pointer to the map
    std::map<int, tilemap>* m_tilemap;

public:
    Editor()
    {
      // Set it to nullptr to avoid error in putABlock if it is called prior to
      // initialization
      m_tilemap = nullptr;
    }

    // Use reference to ensure that there is a tilemap passed. If it is optional
    // us a pointer void target(std::map<int, tilemap>* tilemap)
    void target(std::map<int, tilemap>& tilemap) 
    {
        // Assign the address of the tilemap to the pointer
        m_tilemap = &tilemap;
    }

    void putABlock(sf::Vector3i coord)
    {
        // Ensure here that we're working on something initialize.        
        if (nullptr == m_tilemap)
        {
            // Report error via one of the following method
            // 
            // * assert
            // * exeption
            // * log message

            return;
        }

       /* modify the map*/
       // Here some usage example:
       m_tilemap->insert(std::make_pair(...));
       (*m_tilemap)[...] = ...;
       (*m_tilemap)[...].tilemap_member = ...;
    }

};
```

But I think you should re-work your classes so that the `Editor` calls methods in your `Tilemap`, not work on something held by the other struct.

If the `Tilemap` oulive the `Editor`, I would rather use something like:

```
class Editor
{
private:
    // Use a reference to the map: the tilemap outlive the editor
    Tilemap& m_tilemap;

public:
    Editor(Tilemap& tilemap) :
        m_tilemap(tilemap) // Initialize with the Tilemap already created
    {      
    }



    void putABlock(sf::Vector3i coord)
    {
        // No more test needed here

       /* modify the map */
       m_tilemap.methodOnTilemap(....);
    }

};
```

If the life of the `Tilemap` is the same as the editor I would do:

```
class Editor
{
private:
    // Use a instance of Tilemap 
    Tilemap m_tilemap;

public:
    Editor(/* take potential params to create the tilemap */ ) :
        m_tilemap(/* feed the tilemap with the params*/ ) 
    {      
    }

    void putABlock(sf::Vector3i coord)
    {
        // No more test needed here

       /* modify the map */
       m_tilemap.methodOnTilemap(....);
    }

};
```

If the relative liveliness of each object is very complicated you should have a look to [`std::shared_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

If you think you really need to modify the `std::map<...>` directly, my suggestions regarding liveliness and ref/pointer/shared_ptr still hold.

Comment: Thanks but i've already tried your first method, and when i've tried to modify m_tilemap, it couldn't find any member on it. For example i did "m_tilemap[0].block.setTexture(test);" and compiler said me that "class std::map <int, tilemap>" has no member named block.

Comment: @user3134405 Try `(*m_tilemap)[0]` if you want to access the `tilemap` at index `0` in your `m_tilemap`. I update my answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks it worked ! I'll try your second method later.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the input parameter to be modified in either case you must pass by reference.

```
void target(std::map <int, tilemap>& tilemap) // <---- to target this map
{
    ?
}

void putABlock(sf::Vector3i& coord) // <---- and modify it through several methods...
{
   /* modify the map */
}
```

You are passing by value, thus making a copy of the parameter and then modifying the copy and not the parameter.  Is that the problem?